# What's the difference between the element() and getFirst() methods in the LinkedList class?

Tags: java, linked-list

[`LinkedList`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) has similar descriptions for the `element()` method and the `getFirst()` method (strangely - not the same words).

[`Deque`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) clearly states that the two methods are the same in terms of the return value and the exception.

My question is - why have 2 identical methods? Is it for backward compatibility? Is one approach more efficient than the other?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`element()` is inherited from `Queue` where it makes sense to have only *one* accessing method since all you can do in a queue is remove the first element. However, a deque supports this from *both* ends, necessitating explicit methods to do so.

And it's not very nice to design an API where you would access the first element with `element()` and the last with `getLast()`.

Another thing that might play into this is that `Deque` was added in 1.6, where parts of the ancient parts of the Java Collections Framework have been obsoleted by newer conventions, such as explicit `get~`/`set~` methods for property access. In that context, `getFirst()` and `getLast` more closely adhere to the current Java conventions.

Comment: Actually the get/set convention is not really new, it is actually older than the collection framework (compare the old Vector class to the newer List interface, for example).

Comment: I honestly think that in that case, the element() method should have been phased out. Assuming that's not going to be appreciated by a lot of people, couldn't it at least have been deprecated? Or at the very least, some sort of a guideline in the Javadocs as to which method to pick out of the two. (I'm fairly certain that this is not the only example of duplicate methods in Java).

Comment: @Paŭlo: I guess they don't really care anymore, especially with the collections. While they deprecated like 99 % of Swing and made it more cumbersome, colletions retain methods such as `size()` :|

Answer (score 3):

In Java 1.6, [`LinkedList`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) implements [`Deque`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) (Double-ended Queue). From the [`Deque.element()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html#element%28%29) javadocs:

> Retrieves, but does not remove, the
>   head of the queue represented by this
>   deque (in other words, the first
>   element of this deque). This method
>   differs from peek only in that it
>   throws an exception if this deque is
>   empty.
>
> **This method is equivalent to
>   `getFirst()`**.

In Java 1.5, [`LinkedList`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) has both methods, but [`getFirst()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#getFirst%28%29) is not backed by an interface. My guess is that in Java 1.6 they implemented `Deque` intentionally to include this method.

In Java 1.4, [`LinkedList`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) only has the [`getFirst()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#getFirst%28%29), but it isn't backed by an interface.

Obviously I'd say this is an issue of maintaining backwards compatibility:

- `LinkedList` 1.4 has getFirst() and
  only the `List` interface
- `LinkedList` 1.5 implements [`Queue`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) and hence needs to support the equivalent `elements()` method
- `LinkedList` 1.6 implements `Deque` but because a) it has to remain backwards compatible and b) by policy, all methods should be backed by interfaces, the `Deque` interface also includes the duplicate method

Comment: "LinkedList 1.5 implements Queue and hence needs to support the equivalent elements() method" - for retrieving the first element in a Queue (which is what element() does), doesn't it make perfect sense to just use getFirst() - something that was established from 1.4? (I'm just trying to get it clarified, I'm not trying to dispute).

Comment: @user183037 in 1.4, LinkedList had `getFirst()` and Queue had `element()` but LinkedList doesn't implement Queue yet. Later, when it does, both methods are necessary for backwards compatibility (although their contract is equal)

Comment: I take that back, I just realized Queue was only introduced in 1.5. No, I am puzzled. I guess they didn't want the element() name in the Queue interface.

Answer (score 0):

In a link listed it looks like those are the same. But in a Queue, `element()` seems to be a method to peak at the first element in the queue, but not remove it from the queue.